# Magento xml layout strange behavior

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.9

I'm on a 1.9.3 Magento installation, trying to optimize the existing application.

There is a custom theme, which defines the custom layouts where I found a big mess: duplicated files everywhere, totally absurd overwriting of core behavior, so I tried to tidy up everything, and after one day I succeeded, unless for something really strange that happens in the last step.

I have 2 main layout files: `local.xml and page.xml` and I wanted to merge them in a single file.

Everything works well, until I put all the custom head behavior (cleaned uploaded assets in the single sections), but everything stops working as soon as I merge the custom pages layout.

What I mean is:

**page.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <label>All Pages</label>
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                    <action ..... more js and css.../>
            </block>
            <block...../>
    </default>

    <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
    <page_empty ..../>
    
    <page_one_column ..../>
    
    <page_two_columns_left ..../>
    ....
</layout>
```

**what's left in local.xml**

```
<layout>
    <cms_index_index translate="label">
        <label>CMS Home Page</label>
        <reference name="head"></reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
            </action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
    
    <catalog_product_view .../>
    
    <catalog_category_layered .../>
    
    <catalog_category_default .../>   
</layout>
```

Problems arise as soon as I try to merge the two layouts: minicart and search form disappear, and other elements in the home page gets messed up and duplicated.

What could the possible cause be? There are no other redefinitions in the other layout files in the custom theme that affect the home page or other similar elements. There are obviuosly other layout definitions but each has its own role.
I really dunno where else to search for.
For now I can just leave the two files separated and things work well.

**EDIT:
This was the old local.xml that I've cleaned up.**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        
        <!--CSS and JS Files-->
        <reference name="head">
          <!-- Modifiche per Casabiancheria-->  
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prodotto/product.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prodotto/configurable.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prodotto/calendar.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prodotto/calendar-setup.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/modernizr.custom.min.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/selectivizr.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/matchMedia.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/matchMedia.addListener.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/enquire.js</script></action>
          <!-- 
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/app.js</script></action>
          -->
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/slideshow.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/imagesloaded.js</script></action>
          <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/minicart.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prodotto/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/msrp.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/vendor/msrp_rwd.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jquery.flexslider-min.js</script></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/main.js</script></action>


          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action> 

        </reference>
     

        
        <remove name="footer_links"/>
        <remove name="footer_links2"/>
       
    </default>

<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
             <reference name="head"></reference>

</cms_index_index>
<cms_page>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <alias>cms.wrapper</alias>
            </action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
 <!--Product View-->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <!--CSS and JS Files-->
        <reference name="head">             
        </reference>
          <reference name="content">
          <!--  <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related2.phtml" />-->
          <remove name="product.info.extrahint"/>
          
          <remove name="product.reviews"/>

           <block type="core/template" name="slider" template="catalog/product/list_session.phtml" />
          </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
        <catalog_category_layered>
       <reference name="head">
            <!-- Remove items which the RWD package is not dependent upon -->
                <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</name></action>
        </reference>
      <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
        </action>
      </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>          
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalog_category_default>
      <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
        </action>
      </reference>
       <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>          
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
   
</layout>
```

**EDIT 2: This is the final version I'm actually using of page.xml**

```html
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action> 
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <!-- Remove items which the RWD package is not dependent upon -->
                <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name></action>

                <!-- Add vendor dependencies -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/msrp.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/msrp_rwd.js</script></action>
                
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jquery.flexslider-min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/main.js</script></action>

                <!-- Add stylesheets with no media queries for use in IE 8 and below -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>

                <!-- Add stylesheets with media queries for use by modern browsers -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/roboto-condensed/stylesheet.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontello3/css/fontello.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
               
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
                 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/flexslider.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>

                <!-- Sets viewport meta tag using text block -->
                <block type="core/text" name="head.viewport">
                    <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />]]>&#10;</text></action>
                </block>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
                <label>Page Top</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left_first" as="left_first" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column First (shows above main column on smaller screens)</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.before" as="footer_before" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>footer-before-container</value></action>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
                </block>
                <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
                <!--<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
                </block>-->
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
                <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
            </block>
        </block>
        
        <remove name="footer_links"/>
        <remove name="footer_links2"/>

        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    </default>


    <catalog_product_view>
        <!--CSS and JS Files-->
        <reference name="head">             
        </reference>
          <reference name="content">
          <remove name="product.info.extrahint"/>
          <remove name="product.reviews"/>
           <block type="core/template" name="slider" template="catalog/product/list_session.phtml" />
          </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="head"></reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>          
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>          
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default> 
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What file are you merging them into? I'm assuming you are moving everything into `local.xml` and deleting the `page.xml` file from your theme?

This problem with this is that `local.xml` is loaded last, so any updates to `page.xml` will be lost when you replace blocks from it.

Here's how:
`page.xml` is loaded before `catalog.xml` and `checkout.xml`. Catalog and checkout add additional blocks to the header (such as the mini-cart and search form). But since `local.xml` is loaded last, any blocks that were added to the page xml beforehand, such as `catalog.xml` and `checkout.xml`, are lost in the process.

What you need to do is reference the blocks you need to make changes to, instead of replacing them. So if you need to add a css file to the head, you do this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <!-- add blocks and actions here -->
    </reference>
</default>
```

You'd need to discern between the defaults and the custom modifications and move those modifications over to `local.xml` via referencing. Then you could remove `page.xml` from your theme.

Or...you can keep the code separate.

Comment: Yeah actually what I wanted to to is to delete page.xml and leave only the local.xml. I know about the fallback to the rwd/default or base/default theme, but I checked them and basically, my custom page.xml is a copy of the page.xml in rwd/default, so I was thinking there would be no problem if they were evaluated. At the moment I'm not working on that, but I will go back to it and let you know. Thank you for your help for now. Thumb up!

Comment: If page.xml is a duplicate of the one in `rwd/default`, then there's no need to merge it into local.xml. Just remove page.xml from your theme.

Comment: well i've really tried all possible combinations: removing all duplicates in my page.xml, throw everything in local and delete page, but whenever I take it out, the minicart still disappears. I ended up merging everything inside page.xml and deleting useless handles, just keeping the default layout declarations and custom blocks in some other pages. But it really upsets me that I cannot it totally. Thx indeed

Comment: Hmm. Can you post your merged `local.xml` that is causing problems?

Comment: sure, right now it's my page.xml and i totally deleted the local. I will add it to my question

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem now. I updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you again for your help @Joe, I necessarily ended up with overriding the page.xml and the head section, because i needed to add all the minified versions of the files, so it was quicker to redefine it instead of adding/removing assets. I tried again to put everything in the local.xml, but thigs were messed up in any case, and after analyzing the bunch of layout files i had to keep (because of other extensions) I was not able to find the conflicts. But you helped me understanding what the problem is, even though i cannot find the where and I cannot spend more time on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

why you even define head reference for `cms_index_index` handle?

please give more context about your cleanup and show complete files. A diff to original local.xml would help alot

Comment: Just wanted to keep those handles for the sake of completeness, not to override everything. I will paste the entire old local if you find it useful but i've deleted all the duplicated assets so all references are no more valid